# Why does Android Studio show errors in my code but app still runs

Tags: android-studio

I have recently upgraded my laptop and re-installed Android Studio to the latest version and imported my app.  The problem I am facing now is that when Android Studio start it finishes the gradle build etc, but shows errors all over my code.  I can still debug the app on my phone and all is working.

How can I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Try  Build > Clean. Failing that try restarting Android Studio. Failing that you have compile errors.

Comment: Have tried that and still not clearing the error but can still compile.

Comment: Post the error?

Comment: Okay have it sorted now.  What i did was close android and re-opened as "Administrator" - cleaned project and closed, restarted my machine and all is working now normally.  Thanks

Comment: When i closed Android Studio and restarted my machine same errors all over my code showed.  Only by running as Administrator and then restarted it worked.  Weird??

Comment: Pretty weird. It's like the old joke:

"man goes to doctor:  'it hurts when I lift my arm'
doctor to man: 'well don't lift your arm then'"

Comment: Hahahahahaha :-)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20257448) answer, hope it will help you!

Answer (score 3):

I finally resolved this when it happened to me. The steps I did to resolve my problem

- Build -> clean
- File -> invalidate caches / restart
- Delete .idea folder, close and reopen project

Normally one of the first two first steps is enough but today I actually had to delete the entire .idea folder and reopen the project to get rid of the "errors" (only IDE errors, project still ran for me).

Comment: What fixed it for me was just Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

If Methods named (A) (B) (C) (D), do not help you, then the following 4 steps are AGNI ASTRA.

Step 1 : Go To App Folder In Android Studio.

Step 2 : Locate Build Folder.

Step 3 : Delete Build Folder.

Step 4 : Sync File.

I will advise to use AGNI ASTRA, after trying, Methods named (A) (B) (C) (D) .

The Methods Are :

Method (A)

- CLICK ON FILE IN ANDROID STUDIO
- CLICK ON SYNC PROJECT WITH GRADLE FILES

Method (B)

- CLICK ON FILE IN ANDROID STUDIO
- CLICK ON INVALIDATE CACHES

Method (C)

- CLICK ON BUILD IN ANDROID STUDIO
- CLICK ON CLEAN PROJECT

Method (D)

- CLICK ON BUILD IN ANDROID STUDIO
- CLICK ON REBUILD PROJECT

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Windows), I have faced the same issue with **2 version** of Android Studio,

**1. Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4 (My previous/normal IDE used)**

**2. Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 (My updated/current IDE used)**

First, I thought this problem can be solve by **Build>Clean Project**, or **Build>Rebuild Project**, or **File>Invalidate Caches**..., but sadly ***won't work***. So, I decided to **update** my IDE Arctic Fox to Dolphin.

Download from official site, installed with **different folder** (**C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1**), but project folder still **same**. During opening project, it won't run unless change Java version to **Java 11** (**File>Settings>Build, Exectuion, Deployment>Build Tools>Gradle>Gradle JDK>11 version**).

Try opening several projects, however the IDE sometime still show the **redline code**, **but the app can still debug/run as usual**. Latest method I used, **File>Invalidate Caches...** And IDE ***haven't show any redline code***.

***Remark:** Don't know how long the latest method I used will work.