# Android Studio errors in files but project compiles and run

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem. After I imported a project in Android Studio, in the activity java files it says "cannot resolve symbols" at certain lines, and they are with red, even though the project was fully valid before. The project has all necessary imports too, but some are with red too. The thing is that gradle build is working fine without errors and app launches in the emulator. I have tried invalidate cache and restart and sync gradle with project files. Do you have any ideas. ?[image: screenshot]

Comment: rebuild your project

Comment: @Thunder did that.. gradle build still succeeds and editor still shows errors... why would that be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio inline compiler showing red errors, but compilation with gradle works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226912/android-studio-inline-compiler-showing-red-errors-but-compilation-with-gradle-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

In build.gradle(Module: app) file, update the dependencies and sync.