# Any android Studio version > 3.2.1 show red resource but still compile

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Me and my team are blocked to Android Studio 3.2.1. Any android studio after this one show error for ressource. Ressource are still clickeable/inspectable from editor but are in red. Preview of fragment is KO too.

Work with :
Android Studio 3.2.1
Gradle plugin version 3.2.1
Gradle version 4.6.1

But can't make it works on :
Android Studio 3.5
Gradle plugin version 3.5
Gradle version 5.4.1

I have looked this topic : [Android Studio inline compiler showing red errors, but compilation with gradle works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226912/android-studio-inline-compiler-showing-red-errors-but-compilation-with-gradle-w)

- I have tried to clean/build + invalidate cache and restart.
- I have tried to :

```
rm -rf .idea/caches/
rm -rf .idea/libraries/
rm -rf .gradle/
```

- I also check all XML errors by analysing project and fixing all XML errors
- The package name is correct in AndroidManifest.xml

What else could make this project bug ?

Here is a screenshot of what i got :
[image: screenshot]

We see on it, it s red but still clickeable. My project compile too.

Comment: Not a solution, but I've had this happen on Macbook when having open more than 1 instance of AndroidStudio. Closing the other instance fixed it. Wierd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after long other searchs.

**Solution :**
My problem was i had 3 modules, but 2 of them had the same package name. I rename one and it solved my problem.

**How i solved it:**

- First step, i checked if **java files** was the problems:

  ```
      1) I deleted all my .java files 

      2) Deleted all activity in androidmanifest.xml

      3) create a new empty activity
  ```
- Second step, i checked if **xml files** was the problem:

  ```
      1) I deleted all content in my res folder, except the layout of my empty activity
  ```
- Third step, i checked if **gradle library** was the problem:

  ```
      1) I deleted one by one my dependencies in build.gradle
  ```

I found that my line who was injected the project in the dependencies was the cause of my problems :

```
implementation project(':XXX')
```

1) When i delete it, it was fixed.

2) Therefore, i inspect it and found that if i delete the androidmanifest.xml of XXX project, it solved my problem.

3) Debugging androidmanifest.xml, i found that the id was the problem.

It seems like that androidstudio after 3.2.1 doesn't allow multiple module with same package name. **So, now, all my modules have specific package name.**