# Sudden unresolved reference to various parts of code

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

After building a `signed app bundle` for my Android app, sudden `unresolved reference` errors started appearing everywhere in the code.

[image]

Though the app still compiles and installs successfully, there are errors everywhere.

[image]

[image]

Also a few `interfaces` and `data classes` contained garbage data instead of code.

I've tried:

- Rebuilding the project.
- Cleaning the project.
- Invalidating the cache for the Android Studio.
- Cloning the whole repo in a separate directory and starting all over again. (Still, errors)

But no success.

Comment: Try Invalidate Caches / Restart on your project.

Comment: Already tried but no success.

Comment: That's weird you're saying its compiled and installed successfully isn't it ?

Comment: Yes! It compiles and installs perfectly, but you can't edit code due to errors everywhere.

Comment: Did you make any change in your grades before that error occurred ? Or delete any file ?

Comment: Nothing. I just generated the signed app bundle and errors everywhere.

Comment: Take a look over there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226912/android-studio-inline-compiler-showing-red-errors-but-compilation-with-gradle-w

Comment: First take a backup of the code before performing anything I guess you need to delete .gradle if nothing works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203032/discussion-between-kashish-sharma-and-abhishek).