# Android studio complains with "Cannot access androidx.activity.ComponentActivity" in redline but compiles fine

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio is complaining with `Cannot access androidx.activity.ComponentActivity` in redline, but it's compiling and running fine. I came across many SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226912/android-studio-inline-compiler-showing-red-errors-but-compilation-with-gradle-w) and all suggests clearing cache, removing `.idea` and `.gradle` files, clean project. I've tried everything and I still keep getting this. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Which parent `Activity` class you're inheriting from? also share your version if it's `androidx.appcompat`.

Comment: I'm extending from AppCompatActivity

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

For me updating to the last `appcompat` dependency helped.

Answer (score 2):

for me downgrading appcompat version to 1.4.2 fixed the problem

you should add this to your build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

check the package of `AppCompatActivity`.

In my situation, the `Activity` extends `RxAppCompatActivity` from the `rxlifecycle` library.

But the parent class of `RxAppCompatActivity` in `rxlifecycle2` is `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`.

I change to the 'rxlifecycle3' and the problem is soloved.

Answer (score 0):

Worked on updating appcompat dependency version from

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
```

to

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
```