# all texts in gradle.build is red but it working fine

Tags: android, android-studio

[Build.gradle file screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8D5s.png)

So this is I'm seeing build.gradle file. tho code is working fine. I'm concern about all these red color.
It started happening since I update my android studio to **Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3**

Is there any way to get rid of this ?

Comment: **Check out what they used**
[try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226912/android-studio-inline-compiler-showing-red-errors-but-compilation-with-gradle-w)

Comment: @PraveenKumar I tried it just now. it's not working for me